# pip install vpython not working gives tan error in pycharm and i also tried the way were we go to setting to install still dont work

Tags: python

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement:

```
anyio>=2.0.2 (from jupyter-server>=1.0->jupyter-server-proxy->vpython) (from 
 versions: 1.0.0a1, 1.0.0a2, 1.0.0b1
, 1.0.0b2, 1.0.0rc1, 1.0.0rc2, 1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.4.0)
```

No matching distribution found for:

```
anyio>=2.0.2 (from jupyter-server>=1.0->jupyter-server-proxy->vpython)
```

this was the error more info on this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tOGfjaoSemw

Answer (score 1):

As the error says it means that you are not fulfilling the requirements, either you don't have the minimum python version required or simply pip is too old. Try first to update pip using:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

If it doesn't work you have to dig deeper into anyio package and see what are the pre-requisites for that version.

Comment: it works now when i install anyio from setting in pycharm

Comment: What was the solution in the end? Please write here or accept my answer (if correct) for future readers.

Comment: install anyio https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h-laye1XRHw this video install opencv but insted search anyio  and install latest version